# Dojo autocomplete=on for textfields

Tags: dojo

I had changed my app from using normal html textfields to dijit textfields. After adding the dojo the textfields are not showing the previously entered values in the textfields as soon as i type the first character so that i need not type the text again.. is this the default behaviour of dijit textfield widget. how can i make the textfield autocomplete. please help me. i tried using the below statement in addOnLoad method but no luck

```
dojo.attr(dijit.byId('username').textbox, "autocomplete", "on");
```

Comment: Let me know the browser you are using.

Comment: did you check the autocomplete setting in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

How did you declare your textfield ? The following works for me :

```
<div id="form1" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" method="post">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="on"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="delay" value="2"/>
    <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/psoares/YZeTB/

Comment: I have added the dojoType attribute to struts as following <s:textField dojoType="dijit.form.TextField" id="username" autocomplete="on"/>
T

Comment: There is no such widget named dijit.form.TextField in dojo. The name is dijit.form.TextBox.

Comment: sorry its was a typo error. i gave it as TextBox only but no luck